# I'm trying to scrape stock prices off of Yahoo Finance, and I'm targeting the price. But when I run my code I get "None" in my output

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Here's my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL'
r= requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'})
print(price)
```

The output just returns "None"

Comment: Check response status code!

Comment: The url you'r trying to acess, is returning ``status_code`` of 404 which mean page not found. Instead of doing a web scraping you could instead use some kind of wrapper for eg: [`yfinance`](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) which makes life easier !!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the user agent in the header, here's my working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL'
headers = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
}
r= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find("span", {"class":['Trsdu(0.3s)', 'Fw(b)', 'Fz(36px)', 'Mb(-4px)', 'D(ib)'] })
print(price.contents)

#output
# 200
# ['20,475.42']
```

As other commenters has mentioned, you could use some wrapper library or yahoo finance api.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is being returned a 404 by the server (probably because it is not very legitimate looking). Because of this the html parser can't find what you're looking for hence the output `None`. You can get around this by adding a user-agent to your request like such.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv:geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'})
print(price)
```

But as the commenters mentioned you should really check out their api since Yahoo provides a tool for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the stock data with the `yfinance`library: https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/

It is really useful!. It lets you obtain the information from the different stocks with the ticker. You'll see that it is better than creating a custom scraper.